# grid.arrange and knitr graphic is not displayed in pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, gridextra

I am using `grid.arrange()` from `gridExtra` package to compare 4 histograms. With simple R code this works. However when I use the code in an Rmd knitR Document the graphic is not displayed in the output pdf. A single histogram is displayed. When I run the chunk from the knitr document the graphic is displayed in Rstudio.

----- Code to load edx -----

```
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
if(!require(caret)) install.packages("caret", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
if(!require(data.table)) install.packages("data.table", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(data.table)

# MovieLens 10M dataset:
# https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/10m/
# http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m.zip

dl <- tempfile()
download.file("https://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m.zip", dl)

ratings <- fread(text = gsub("::", "\t", readLines(unzip(dl, "ml-10M100K/ratings.dat"))),
                 col.names = c("userId", "movieId", "rating", "timestamp"))

movies <- str_split_fixed(readLines(unzip(dl, "ml-10M100K/movies.dat")), "\\::", 3)
colnames(movies) <- c("movieId", "title", "genres")


# if using R 4.0 or later:
movies <- as.data.frame(movies) %>% mutate(movieId = as.numeric(movieId),
                                           title = as.character(title),
                                           genres = as.character(genres))


movielens <- left_join(ratings, movies, by = "movieId")

# Validation set will be 10% of MovieLens data
set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding") # if using R 3.5 or earlier, use `set.seed(1)`
test_index <- createDataPartition(y = movielens$rating, times = 1, p = 0.1, list = FALSE)
edx <- movielens[-test_index,]
temp <- movielens[test_index,]

# Make sure userId and movieId in validation set are also in edx set
validation <- temp %>% 
  semi_join(edx, by = "movieId") %>%
  semi_join(edx, by = "userId")

# Add rows removed from validation set back into edx set
removed <- anti_join(temp, validation)
edx <- rbind(edx, removed)

rm(dl, ratings, movies, test_index, temp, movielens, removed)
```

---

```r
edx %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=rating)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(edx$rating), 
                                  max(edx$rating), 
                                  by = 0.5))
```

Distribution of ratings for the different categories

```r
hist_drama <- edx %>% 
  filter(str_detect(genres, "Drama")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rating)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.5, 5, by = 1)) +    
    labs(title="Drama")
    
hist_comedy <- edx %>% 
  filter(str_detect(genres, "Comedy"))  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rating)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.5, 5, by = 1)) + 
    labs(title="Comedy")
    
hist_thriller <- edx %>% 
  filter(str_detect(genres, "Thriller"))  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rating)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.5, 5, by = 1)) + 
    labs(title="Thriller")
    
hist_romance <- edx %>% 
  filter(str_detect(genres, "Romance"))  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rating)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.5, 5, by = 1)) + 
    labs(title="Romance")
    
grid.arrange(hist_drama, 
             hist_comedy, 
             hist_thriller,
             hist_romance, 
             ncol = 2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide the data for `edx` so we can run this ourselves?

Comment: I have provided the code above